# How can I subtract or get compare difference in values within the same column from the top result column result as the base?

Tags: mysql

#### Table *tbl*

| id | name | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v | 10 |
| 2 | w | 11 |
| 3 | x | 9 |
| 4 | y | 7 |
| 5 | z | 15 |

#### Table *tbl2*

| id | name | result | result-diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | v | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | w | 11 | +1 |
| 3 | x | 9 | -1 |
| 4 | y | 7 | -3 |
| 5 | z | 15 | +5 |

Column `result-diff` is based on the difference between the `id` row minus the top `id`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Related: *[Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using [FIRST_VALUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value) window function (which requires MySQL 8+)

Data example

```
create table tbl(
  id int,
  name varchar(30),
  result int );

insert into tbl values 
  (1,'v',10), (2,'w',11), (3,'x',9),
  (4,'y',7), (5,'z',15);
```

Query

```
select id,
       name,
       result,
       result - first_value(result) over(order by id asc) as result_diff
from tbl;
```

Result

```
id  name    result  result_diff
 1   v        10       0
 2   w        11       1
 3   x         9      -1
 4   y         7      -3
 5   z        15       5
```

---

Another option , CROSS JOIN

Query

```
select t.id,
       t.name,
       t.result,
       t.result - first_result as result_diff
from tbl t 
cross join (select id,
                   result as first_result 
            from tbl 
            order by id asc limit 1
            ) first_val
```

[See example](https://dbfiddle.uk/VtjqGm4a)

Comment: Perfect!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @SpawnRivera I'm glad it helped you. If you want the plus sign in the result you can add a case condition as described [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VtjqGm4a), but it seem excess to me.

Comment: I Think this is enough, Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Ergest Basha Can it be use to update the time_diff column? thanks

Comment: @SpawnRivera something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/3mfFFIia) ?

Comment: Yes! Thank you again!!!